# Get color that is applied to UIButton background image on press

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a subclass of a UIButton. Right now, I'm using a background image of a play icon so that it scales properly between orientation changes. When you press down on the button, the play icon darkens as expected. When you release, it returns to its original color. This is implemented by iOS by default.

Here's where my custom UIButton comes into play. I override the drawRect method to draw a grey circle around the play icon. What I want to happen is when a user presses down on the button, I update a color property to be equal to the darkened color of the play icon, but I'm not sure how to get that color.

tintColor is not the property I am looking for, as that always reports a blue color by default. How do I access the background image's tint that seems to be applied when the UIButton is in a selected state?

Fwiw, I am writing this in Swift 2.3.

Comment: I'm not seeing any code so I may be way off. I have two ideas, which I'll separate in two comments. Both may (at the very least) require some refactoring of your approach. The first thought is if you are using images in your UIButton subclass, then why not find the correct images and import them into your app? (You can do this even if it's a framework.) Find a suitable app, control-click, and view the contents of that app. I know, you may in fact be breaking some IP rule. Nonetheless, that's my first thought.

Comment: My second thought. Code a bit deeper than simply subclassing UIButton. All you get there is UIButtonState, which sounds like it doesn't suffice. But the base class of a UIButton is UIControl. Also, the base class of any view (UIControl?) is UIView. At some point your can roll your own events - meaning you can get to **touchDown**. Tap into *that* layer of events and you can find what you need I think.

Comment: Thank you! The reason we don't just have images of the buttons with the circle that I'm currently drawing is because the image provided by the customer is already slightly off center and we need to animate over the grey circle to line up perfectly. Back when I tried to have a circle as part of the image, the animation that I draw would always be a pixel or two off.
**EDIT**: Even adjusting the position in code of the animation would still result in imperfect results.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm being naïve, but why not break out the Digital Color Meter app, measure the color of the pressed button, and use that RGB value in your code? It's not very future proof should Apple change the visual behavior of a button press, but I don't think your approach is future proof either.